# Рассчет расстояний между парами точек в двумерном евклидовом пространстве. Координаты точек заданы двумя векторами: `X` и `Y`

Tags: python, vector, numpy, вектор

Задание больше математическое, проблема в том, что непонятна формулировка и из-за этого не удается написать функцию.

Comment: логично ведь, что уточнения формулировки имеет смысл спрашивать у того, кто выдал такую формулировку.

Comment: Тот, кто выдал такую формулировку, считает ее верной.

Comment: Метод norm чего нужно использовать? Я в целом могу понять или додумать смысл всех моментов условия, кроме вот этого пункта.

Comment: Названия векторов имеют отношение к осям `X` и `Y`? Другими словами - задача о точках в двухмерном пространстве?

Comment: @MaxU, я думаю, что преподаватель автора вопроса имел в виду, что имеется отдельно список координат X, и отдельно список координат Y, и чтобы получить сами точки, нужно делать zip. Но вообще, конечно, нужно бить ссаными тряпками тех преподавателей, которые дают задания в такой формулировке.

Comment: @Александр, да уж, формулировочка та еще ...

Comment: @Alex, функция должна вернуть список растояний между всеми парами заданных точек?

Comment: @MaxU, в этом то и есть вся проблема, что ничего непонятно... думала, вдруг я чего-то не понимаю, поэтому и разместила вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Если исходить из того что на вход подаются два вектора - координаты иксов `x` и игреков `y` для всех точек и вернуть необходимо расстояния между всеми парами точек:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

x = np.random.randint(10*5, size=5)
y = np.random.randint(10*5, size=5)

def my_beautiful_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean'):
    """
    передавайте преподавателю привет с [ru.stackoverflow.com]
    и скажите что ему следует научиться формулировать задачи
    """
    # оптимизированное по скорости решение
    metric = 'cityblock' if mode=='manhattan' else mode
    return pdist(np.column_stack((x, y)),metric=metric)
```

результат:

```
In [186]: x
Out[186]: array([36, 29, 20, 18,  7])

In [187]: y
Out[187]: array([26, 31, 14, 19,  0])

In [188]: my_beautiful_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean')
Out[188]: array([ 8.60232527, 20.        , 19.31320792, 38.94868419, 19.23538406, 16.2788206 , 38.01315562,  5.38516481, 19.10497317, 21.9544984 ])

In [189]: my_beautiful_dist(x, y, mode='manhattan')
Out[189]: array([12., 28., 25., 55., 26., 23., 53.,  7., 27., 30.])
```

в виде матрицы расстояний:

```
In [190]: squareform(my_beautiful_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean'))
Out[190]:
array([[ 0.        ,  8.60232527, 20.        , 19.31320792, 38.94868419],
       [ 8.60232527,  0.        , 19.23538406, 16.2788206 , 38.01315562],
       [20.        , 19.23538406,  0.        ,  5.38516481, 19.10497317],
       [19.31320792, 16.2788206 ,  5.38516481,  0.        , 21.9544984 ],
       [38.94868419, 38.01315562, 19.10497317, 21.9544984 ,  0.        ]])

In [191]: squareform(my_beautiful_dist(x, y, mode='manhattan'))
Out[191]:
array([[ 0., 12., 28., 25., 55.],
       [12.,  0., 26., 23., 53.],
       [28., 26.,  0.,  7., 27.],
       [25., 23.,  7.,  0., 30.],
       [55., 53., 27., 30.,  0.]])
```

---

неоптимизированная версия с использованием [np.linalg.norm()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
def my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean'):
    points = np.column_stack((x, y))
    if mode == 'euclidean':
        return [np.linalg.norm(a-b) for a,b in combinations(points, 2)]
    if mode == 'manhattan':
        return [np.linalg.norm(a-b, ord=1) for a,b in combinations(points, 2)]
    return None
```

проверка:

```
In [201]: my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean')
Out[201]:
[8.602325267042627,
 20.0,
 19.313207915827967,
 38.948684188300895,
 19.235384061671343,
 16.278820596099706,
 38.01315561749642,
 5.385164807134504,
 19.1049731745428,
 21.95449840010015]

In [202]: my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='manhattan')
Out[202]: [12.0, 28.0, 25.0, 55.0, 26.0, 23.0, 53.0, 7.0, 27.0, 30.0]

In [203]: my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='manhattan') == pdist(np.column_stack((x, y)),metric='cityblock')
Out[203]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

In [204]: (my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='manhattan') == pdist(np.column_stack((x, y)),metric='cityblock')).all()
Out[204]: True

In [205]: (my_horrible_dist(x, y, mode='euclidean') == pdist(np.column_stack((x, y)),metric='euclidean')).all()
Out[205]: True
```

Comment: `combinations` - это `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @godva, да, спасибо, что напомнили!